Webview wss streaming is not working in Iphone
Wss streaming is not working in iphone using video tag. I am passing all the options for evowsplayer. It is not returning to play mode. The same code is working in Android fine.
The code here:
playerObj= new EvoWsPlayer(opts);
playerObj.play();

Load the video and play in a video tag. How to solve the issue?
